# failed to Loop Through All tables and Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

i was working on database script in which i required to loop through all tables and column, my script is

```
begin
declare @counter int, @tblName varchar(50), @columnNames varchar(100),@collection varchar(200)
SET @counter=1
SET @tblName=''
SET @columnNames=''
SET @collection=''
WHILE @counter<=(SELECT COUNT(table_name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
begin
    select @tblName=table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME not in (@collection)
    select @columnNames=@columnNames + column_name+' : ' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=@tblName

    if(@counter=1)
    SET @collection = @tblName
    else
    SET @collection = @collection +','+@tblName

    Print 'Table : '+@tblName
    Print 'Columns : '+@columnNames
    Print 'Collection : '+@collection

    SET @counter = @counter+1
end
end
```

but the problem is it is only iterating through 2 tables, what i figured out is problem is in this part

```
WHERE table_name not in (@collection)
```

but im unable to sort this out..

my output is

```
Table : tbl1
Columns : column1 : Column 2 : column 3
Collection : tbl1

Table : tbl2
Columns : column1 : Column 2 : column 3
Collection : tbl1,tbl2

Table : tbl1
Columns : column1 : Column 2 : column 3
Collection : tbl1,tbl2,tbl1
```

thanx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a string containing `'a,b,c'` as a *set* for `IN()` (because its not a set).

Instead declare a table variable:

```
declare @collection table (name varchar(max) not null)
```

and insert `@tblName` into it within your loop:

```
insert @collection values (@tblName)
```

And modify the `where` clause:

```
... where TABLE_NAME not in (select name from @TableVar)
```